# How to get a consistent behavior for a rigid body hooked platform?

Tags: godot, rigidbody, rigid-body-dynamics

Consider this platform made of `RigidBody2D` and `PinJoint2D` objects:

[image]

`PinJoint2D` setup is:

- `Softness` = 0
- `Bias` = 0.9

When I set the mass of the platform with high value, the structure starts to shake like this:

[image]

Why is this happening and how to fix that?

Comment: [Here's a GDC Vault talk explaining some common physics quirks like this](https://gdcvault.com/play/1021921/Designing-with-Physics-Bend-the).  Objects of very different masses tend to be much harder for joints to solve nicely.

Comment: The Godot devs are working on a brand new, custom physics system for Godot, maybe it'll fix this issue.  Here's the link to the progress report:  https://godotengine.org/article/physics-progress-report-1